# GetType() == type performance

Tags: c#, types, gettype

I am making a XNA game and I am calling following code 2 to 20 times per update. I tried googling and it seems like this is semi-slow, so I just thought I'd ask if there is any faster way to compare types?

Code:

```
    public Modifier this[Type type]
    {
        get
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.Count; i++)
            {
                if (this[i].GetType() == type)
                {
                    return this[i];
                }
            }

            throw new NotImplementedException("Fix this");
        }

        set
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.Count; i++)
            {
                if (this[i].GetType() == type)
                {
                    this[i] = value;
                }
            }

            if(System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
```

This code is in ModifierCollection class which inherits from a List. Modifier is a part of particle engine. Also, my game isnt in condition where I can actually test this yet so I cant test this, but this should work right?

I read something about RunTimeTypeHandles which should be faster, should I use it?

EDIT: What I am aiming to do with this is that I can do the following:

```
    (particleEffect["NameOfEmitter"].Modifiers[typeof(SomeCoolModifier)] as SomeCoolModifier).Variable = Value;
```

Basically I just want to change the value of some Modifiers in runtime.

EDIT 2: I just realized that I can just save the reference of Modifier to the class where I am at the moment calling this :P Maybe not as clean code if I have 5-10 modifiers but should remove this problem.

Comment: Why do you need a mapping indexed by a *type*? The only use I can imagine for this is metaprogramming, and doesn't happen 20 times per frame. Are you sure you can't just use polymorphism?

Comment: Not a duplicate but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378643/fastest-type-comparison should help.

Comment: It's advisable to have more explicit exception data: `NotImplementedException("Fix this");`

Comment: @mydogisbox: Probably safe to assume that's more of a `// TODO: ` placeholder.

Comment: @Yuck Possible, but its following an if statement, so I would assume otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need any of the extra functionality exposed by `Type`, and you're only concerned with absolute equality between types--i.e., you don't need to support inheritance--`RuntimeTypeHandle` is the fastest way to do this comparison.

Really, though, I would question whether this isn't a weakness of your class design.  Unless you have a compelling reason to check the type directly, it's probably better to expose some sort of value (probably an enum) on your objects that represents what they are, and do your comparisons against that.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the values in a dictionary indexed by type rather than a list so you wouldn't have to do an O(n) iteration over the list each time.

As noted in the comments, this does depend on the size of n and may be a micro-optimization. I'd recommend profiling your application.

Comment: Well, depends. If there are only ever a handful of items, the hashing and the fancies lookup algorithm may make it slower than linear search, and how much the JIT knows about hashtable internals and the scope of the collection, among other things, may have influence as well.

Comment: That doesn't get rid of the GetType() call which, if the list is small, will probably be more expensive than a loop

Comment: @delnan - true, it does depend on the size of n. Revising my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be *really* fast and can trust the code that is calling you, change the indexer to just take an int.  Then in whatever method (which you didn't show) that callers use to add Types to the list, return back to them the corresponding int.  It's a worse API but it means you don't have to do any loops or lookups.